# EventSource messages not received in Firefox

Tags: http, firefox, eventsource

I have a server that sends a test `EventSource` message like this:

Request:

```
GET /web/stream/status HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1010
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/event-stream
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:1010/web/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1miz08s4nu74q11sm7y44uwu2b
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.0.6.v20130930)

event: data
data: hello
```

All lines are terminated with `\r\n`. So that looks right to me but if I try this in Firefox...

```
var source = new EventSource('/web/stream/status');
source.onmessage = function(event) { console.log(event); };
source.onerror = function(event) { console.log(event); };
```

... then it connects and performs the request exactly as above (in fact I copied the session from Wireshark into telnet to test it), and according to Wireshark the `event: data` stuff is sent, but neither the `onmessage` nor `onerror` handlers are called. `onerror` is called when I stop the server.

No data is ever shown in the Response tab of the network thingy.

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha I found the answer! Firefox does not like the `;charset=UTF-8`. The spec says that you can have `;charset=utf-8` which Firefox allows.

Rather strict interpretation of the spec but fair enough.

Furthermore, you only get `onmessage()` for lone `data:` lines. If the `data:` is preceeded by and `event:` name then `onmessage()` is not called - instead you have to use this:

```
source.addEventListener('name_of_my_event', myEventHandler, false);
```